Error in merging the columns of multiple .csv files during Multiple Linear regression in R
I am trying to apply multiple linear regression between 4 predictors and 1 response variable using R. All these variables exist in separate .csv files , as there are more than 1000 data points in each file. I am trying to merge all files based on a common key column "Year".
Here 'Temp', 'Ppt', 'ET', 'WS' are predictor variables, and 'SM' is a response variable.
my dataset looks like this:
Temperature data:



Year
ST1




1991
16.4


1992
17


1993
16.9


1994
18.9


1995
17.2


1996
18.2



Ppt data:



Year
ST1




1991
2


1992
5


1993
2


1994
4


1995
8


1996
7



ET data:



Year
ST1




1991
3


1992
4.5


1993
6.4


1994
4.5


1995
5.3


1996
18.2



WS data



Year
ST1




1991
3


1992
3.4


1993
4.2


1994
4.5


1995
3.4


1996
5.3



SM data (response variable)



Year
ST1




1991
10.2


1992
14.5


1993
16.4


1994
14.5


1995
15.3


1996
12.3



I am trying following script:
setwd('D:/MLR/NEW')
df <- read.csv("SM.csv")
df1<- read.csv("TEMP.csv")
df2<- read.csv("PPT.csv")
df3<- read.csv("WS.csv")
df4<- read.csv("ET.csv")

response_variable <- "df$st1"
predictor_variables <- c("df1$st1", "df2$st1","df3$st1","df4$st1")

formula <- as.formula(paste(response_variable, "~", paste(predictor_variables, collapse = "+")))

merged_d <- merge(df1, df2, df3, df4, by = "Year")  ##Error occur in this line of code, it doesn't work for more than two files ###
merged <- merge(merged_d, df, by = "Year")

model9 <- lm(formula, data = merged)

I am trying to figure out to apply it only multiple files, on multiple grid points at once and want to pull out coefficients for each grid point.
Seeking for any any guidance or help.
Many thanks in advance.
